# "no data provided" error in json PUT request

Tags: rest, curl, https, http-headers

I am trying to PUT json data through curl request.
Currently I am getting "no data provided" error.

```
 curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request PUT -d @a.json https://localhost:8200/api/login
```

> {"errors":["no data provided"]}

```
cat a.json
{
  "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2"
}
```

While when I am Posting it with double quotes and not through file its working.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --request PUT -d "{\"data\":{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}} " https://localhost:8200/api/login
```

Answer (score 4):

We need to pass data section in Json.

```
cat a.json
{
  "data": {
  "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2"
}
}
```

Comment: to create the secret using above payload use below command. Replace the tokenvalue with your own vault token                                                                                                               curl  -H "X-Vault-Token: tokenvalue"  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST   -d @a.json   http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/data/new-key